# I want to make my MacBook Pro's security settings location-aware and automatic

Tags: macos, mac, security, context

I travel back and forth, using the same macbook pro at the office as I do at home.  How can I get my MacBook Pro to recognize when it's at home and doesn't need to keep bringing up the password screen every few minutes *without* having to go into settings every time?  I want my computer to sense when I connect to the LAN network at work and tighten up security and then sense my home wifi network and change the security settings.